# Render time in Blender 2.91.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

[image]..I have question, how long would it take you to render 1675 frames -Animation- in a Blender using Cycles /Supported / CPU ....
am using
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12 Core 3.80Ghz , 64 GB Ram, Windows 10 64 bit,
( in Open CL  Radeon Graphics cards Rx 570 8 GB I have big problem with GPU When I switch the rendering device to GPU compute and to OpenCL, in blender 2.91, it just crashes.
The CPU rending works fine but whenever I try to use the GPU for rendering Blender just STOPS and freeze PC and then it restarts itself)

Vertices- 60.137 | Faces 59.857 | Tris 119.650 … mine render on CPU was about 25 h is that Normal time ?
GPU Driver is 20.4 stable/recomended version of drivers, they work on my Eevee and Cycles ok... showing textures on Blender viewport, but freezes when select Gpu rendering

GPU Driver: Radeon Adrenalin 2020 edition 20.11. PROBLEM
Eevee render is broken, with everything deactivated does not showing Textures or picture, the only way to get Eevee to work properly is activating "High quality normals" under Render > Performance, then Eevee just works perfectly but Cycles is Broken same.

If anyone knows how to enable GPU and speed up Rendering let me know....Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hello :). 25 hrs means roughly 55seconds per frame. It's hard to judge whether that's fast/slow without the file. Please, consider sharing one :).

Comment: I'll add that although some people have had success using high quality normals to fix the AMD shading issue, a more universally effective solution (for now) is to roll back your graphics drivers to an earlier version. Hopefully AMD or blender (or both) will implement a more elegant fix in the future.

Comment: @JachymMichal all on Minimum 55 sec per frame on CPU, 
thank you for the answer, I appreciate it

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yap 
I sincerely hope it fixes those problems, thanks for the reply

Comment: Do not render as video directly, render as an image sequence first and then encode as video. To find out how long it would take, render one frame and multiply that by the number of desired frames to get an estimate of the total render time.

Comment: @susuI am grateful for your answer